# Atom Editor / Sublime Text - Code formatter that respect .editorconfig and .jscsrc

Tags: sublimetext, formatter, atom-editor, jscs, editorconfig

Is there any code formatter plugin for **Atom Editor & Sublime Text** that respect `.editorconfig` & `.jscsrc` files?

For example, if my `.editorconfig` has the following settings

```
# 4 space indentation
[*.js]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
```

and `.jscsrc` does not state anything about indentation, I would like to see my code being indented with 4 spaces along with other rules specified at `.jscsrc` when I format the code (not auto format).

I would not prefer to maintain same configuration across multiple config files.

Answer (score 2):

Both Editors have plugins available to both lint and auto fix files according to your `.jscsrc` and `.editorconfig` files:

---

#### Sublime Text

**`.editorconfig`** - [EditorConfig](https://github.com/sindresorhus/editorconfig-sublime) will format files automatically.

**`.jscsrc`** - [SublimeLinter-jscs](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-jscs) will do in-line linting for you, and [SublimeJSCSFormatter](https://github.com/TheSavior/SublimeJSCSFormatter) will auto-format with the keyboard shortcuts:

- Linux/Windows: `Ctrl + Shift + H`
- Mac: `Cmd + Shift + H`

---

#### Atom

**`.editorconfig`** - [EditorConfig](https://github.com/sindresorhus/atom-editorconfig) will format files automatically (same name as the one for Sublime, different project).

**`.jscsrc`** - [linter-jscs](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-jscs) will do in-line linting for you, and [jscs-fixer](https://github.com/foliveira/jscs-fixer) allows you to auto-format a file:

- From Command Palette invoke `jscs Fixer: Fix`
- Right-click on one of the selected files and choose `Fix this file using jscs`
- Use the keyboard shortcut - `Ctrl+⌂+J`

Comment: Thanks for your concerns, does it respect the .editorconfig file too?

Comment: @sarbbottam, added relevant options

Comment: I have updated the OP with example could you take look?

Comment: The EditorConfig plugin will automatically format the code when you save the file based on your `.editorconfig` file.  To format using your `.jscsrc` you currently only have the above options.  So your work flow would look something like: 1. write code, 2. use keyboard shortcut to format code according to `.jscsrc`, 3. save file (code is formatted automatically according to `.editorconfig`).  Though 2 and 3 are interchangeable.  So you wouldn't need to maintain configuration against multiple files; just use either/both depending on the settings you need and there need not be duplicates.